# single AZ to multiple AZ aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have created an aurora instance with multi AZ - "No" and migrated my existing data from existing external mysql slave to Aurora using DMS successfully.

Now when I go to modify instance, it does not allow me to set multi AZ - "create replica in different zone"

is it possible to modify multi az in aurora?

Comment: IIRC Multi-AZ in Aurora is only really a convenience feature, launching master + replica together.  Unlike RDS for MySQL, the backup node remains usable for reads.  Simply creating a replica after the fact should have the same result.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like as part of this post?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this. Just go ahead and use the `create-db-instance` API via aws cli and mention the same `db-cluster-identifier` as before.

This should be possible via Console as well, not sure why you were not able to choose "Create Replica in different zone.". Is that still the case?